# Vectorial function: evaluating an integral

Tags: integration, vector-fields

Given the vectorial function
$$F(t)=\frac{4}{t}i+t^2j+1k$$
I have to evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{1}F(t)dt$$
However,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{4}{t}dt=+\infty$$
What is supposed to be the right answer to
$$\int_{0}^{1}F(t)dt?$$

Comment: What is the context of this integral? I wonder if $\int_0^1F(t)\,dt$ is some abuse of notation for a line integral, perhaps intended to refer to the integral of $F(t)$ along some path over the range $0<t<1$.

Comment: @user170231 it's just a "normal" integral.

Comment: The integral is linear so:$$\int \langle x(t),y(t),z(t)\rangle dt=i\int x(t) dt+k\int y(t) dt+j\int z(t) dt$$

Comment: @TymaGaidash so the answer is the vector: $(\infty,1/3,1)$?

Comment: @mvfs314 according to [Paul’s Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/VectorFcnsCalculus.aspx), yes.